# CAKEPHP: Inner joins and Controller Issues

Tags: cakephp, controller, inner-join

http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/clients

http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1402280124

The first link- where add is- it is working fine, but the inner join is not working. The SQL is correct, just not the code in the controller. Another issue I am having is the undefined action views. I am certain it has to do with what's inside the controller.

```
<?php
class ClientsController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Clients';
    function index()
    {
        $this->set('Clients', $this->Client->find('all'));
    }
    function add()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->SetFlash('Client has been saved');
                $this->redirect(array(
                    'action' => 'index'
                ));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Nope');
            }
        }
    }
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $this->Client->id = $id;
        $this->set('Client', $this->Client->read(null, $id));
    }
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $this->Client->id = $id;
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $this->request->data = $this->Client->read();
        } else {
            if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Client has been updated.');
                $this->redirect(array(
                    'action' => 'index'
                ));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update Client.');
            }
        }
        $this->loadModel('Employee');
        $this->set('Employees', $this->Employee->find('list', array(
            'order' => array(
                'Employee.name'
            )
        )));
        $this->set(compact('Employees'));
    }
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        if ($this->request->is('/Clients/delete/{id}')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        if ($this->Client->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The Client with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
            $this->redirect(array(
                'action' => 'index'
            ));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: can you please post your code here?

Comment: I am not 100%, I am certain that all of it is the latest.

Comment: What *exactly* is the question here? What inner join problem? The example you linked complains about missing actions, not views. Are you sure you set up your routes correctly? That the link you sent has the code you posted here? This question is way too vague to be answered at this point.